# Unable to choose build for watch app in App Store Connect

Tags: watchos

I am trying to submit a standalone watchOS app to the Apple App Store Connect for review. The builds I have submitted have come from XCode Cloud and have been successfully tested in TestFlight. When I click the button to add a build for app review, I see my builds in the list, but I cannot select any of them. The radio buttons do not register any clicks. There is no warning message or other information about why the builds cannot be selected. It just looks like a malfunctioning user interface, although I suspect there is an underlying reason.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AedBj.jpg)

I have tried using Chrome, Safari and Firefox, on PC and Mac, clicking vigorously as well as using the space bar and tab key. I have also tried changing the version number such that it complies with convention (1.12.0 in my case). Is it perhaps related to having a standalone watch app with no companion phone app? Is there something else I am missing? I can find no supporting documentation about this problem.